# Dependence of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

In a Bernoulli experiment of parameter $p$ let $T$ be the instant of first success and $U$ the instant of second success. Find the density of $U$ and tell if $T$ and $U$ are independent or not.

This is what I've done: since $U$ is the instant of second success we have that:
$$p_U(k)=\mathbb{P}[U=k]=p^2(1-p)^{k-2}$$
since it is not relevant where is the instant of first success, because we know that in every case we have $2$ successes and $k-2$ insuccesses. At the same time, we have that:
$$p_{T,U}(m,n)=\mathbb{P}[T=m,\ U=n]=p(1-p)^{m-1}(1-p)^{n-m-1}p=p^2(1-p)^{n-2}=p_U(n)\neq p_T(m)p_U(n)$$
Since $T \sim $ Geo$(p)$. So they are not independent. Is it correct or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the density, you forgot an additional factor $k-1$ for all the possible positions for the first success. Look up the negative binomial distribution.

For the dependence, your proof works. Here is an alternative: note that we must always have $T<U$. This means they must be dependent, because $$P(U=n, T=m)=0\neq P(U=n)P(T=m)$$
if $n<m$.